# How to choose field from model by current locale in Angular

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, locale, translation

AngularJs.
I have a model like this

```
animal: {name_en: "cat", name_de: "Kater", name_ru: "кот"}
```

So I want to use in html template appropriate field. 
Something like this:

```
<div>{{ if(locale == 'en') animal.name_en }}</div>
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can easily do that in AngularJS.

Putting a hardcoded check would be difficult to scale when you'll have a lot of animals to handle :)

So, modifying a bit of your structure. Have the `animals` to be an array of Objects. Something like:

```
$scope.animals = [{name: "ABC", locale: "en"}, {name: "XYZ", locale: "de"}];
```

Assuming you have `en` as selected locale

```
$scope.selectedlocale = 'en';
```

Now, just iterate over the `animals` Array and render accordingly:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals">
    <div ng-if="animal.locale === selectedLocale">
        {{ animal.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**

`ng-show` - let the element to be in DOM but hidden if condition fails

`ng-if` - let the element not to be in DOM if condition fails just that it adds extra watchers, if that isn't the problem you have.

Comment: Thanks, I think that it would work.
But how do you get curent locale? Now I am trying to use moment, but it always return default locale.

Comment: You can explicitly set it to `en` and provide a dropdown where user can select his own and accordingly update your views. Second option is use: `navigator.language` or `moment.locale();`

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it fulfils the question's requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

Better would be:

```
<div ng-if="locale == 'en'">{{animal.name_en}}</div>
```

If you would do that by this way:

```
<div>{{ if(locale == 'en') animal.name_en }}</div>
```

You will have div always rendered, if you use ng-if then element will be rendered only when expression return true